# Using defined smarty variable as object key

Tags: smarty

I want to access the data of the object that comes as a smarty variable according to the variable I have defined.

I'm actually expecting like {$page->page_meta->description} as I wrote below. But nothing happens. It doesn't give an error. What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: why just not `$page->page_meta->meta` ? What is `$meta` variable?

Comment: It didn't work that way either, it was null. Shouldn't the values ​​defined as item in the foreach be used starting with '$'? If we use it as ->meta, it will look for it in smarty variable and it will be null as a result. Here in the first foreach the $meta value should have come as a description.

Answer (score 1):

Ok now I understand what you mean.

```
{foreach $metas as $meta}
    {$page->page_meta->{$meta}}
{/foreach}
```

PS next time do not insert screenshots like this but write code

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I tried that too and the problem was not solved. I guess there is no such use on objects. But it's strange that it doesn't.

Comment: I would like to point out that there is no problem with the data that comes as a smarty variable. ************** Data: ->page_meta = stdClass Object (2) ->description = "123" ->keywords = "a,b,c"

Comment: This must work - I test it. Check it again please. If doesn't - update your Smarty engine.

Comment: I've checked again and it still doesn't work, i am sure. Smarty version is 3.1.x. Do you know if it works in this version?

Comment: I check it on this version (3.1.x) and it works. You must write exactly like this: `{$page->page_meta->{$meta}}`